# Remove inner toolbar from view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library, list-view

I created a view for my document library with toolbar type "show toolbar". This gives the desired result, but also shows a 'inner toolbar' within the view. How to hide/remove this toolbar?

[image]

Comment: That is the View Selector and displays 3 of the available views. You could hide it with JavaScript; there is no OOTB setting to hide it.

Comment: Agree with Danny , if you want to hide you can use CSS to hide it .
.ms-pivotControl-container
{
  display:none;
}

Comment: @BhaskarDhone thank. I added the css to my master page unfortunately  without any result.

Comment: try to add this : .ms-pivotControl-container
{display:none !important} after adding clear cache and try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide this inner toolbar with the miscellaneous settings of the web part:

- Check: Disable view selector menu
- Check: Disable 'save this view' button
- Uncheck: Display search box

[image]